# Even if the character array is mentioned then why is that when we use scanf it takes more than that and even prints(in C)

Tags: c, arrays

I was doing a simple program say suppose i have declared a char array as name[5]
then when i use scanf with %s the input from me is taken with the lenghth more than that until a white space or '\0' is expected. I just wanted to know that if i am declaring an array with with limit 5 then why does it not stop at length 5 while printing and why it even prints   "Iamtopofthisworld" rather than "Iamto".
Pgm

```
char name[5];
printf("Enter the character");
scanf("\t%s",&name);
printf("\nThe output obtaiend from user %s",name);
```

PLEASE ANYONE HELP ME IN THIS DOUBT

Answer (score 4):

- in C language, the (typical) system doesn't check if you are accessing inside the array, so the printing won't stop at 5 characters.
- to limit the input length to 5 chars, you can use `%5s`.
- to save the terminating null character, you have to allocate 6 bytes for reading 5 characters. I mean that you should use `char name[6];`.
- you should pass `name` instead of `&name` to scanf. The type differs.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike your solution works .... but i just wanted to knw  that since a string is a 1D array of characters (and this array of character is already  declared as "name" in (1st line with length 5) and passed near scan then also why needed to mention %5s to stop at 5th position...

Comment: A good program does not store too much data in `name[]`, so no reason for C to create code to manage, limit and slow array access.  If code needs the language to check boundaries, suggests another language.  Welcome to coding without a safety net.